# Unity saving file on Android

Tags: unity, android

I'm attempting to save player data into a `Saves` folder like so:

```
string relPath = "Saves/saveData.txt";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(relPath);
file.Directory.Create();
// File.WriteAllText(relPath, JsonUtility.ToJson(data));
```

The issue I'm having is that `file.Directory.Create();` works on my PC (Windows 11) but not on my Android device.  Am I missing something, maybe in build settings or maybe permissions on the device?  Is there a better (i.e. more universal) option for creating a directory?

Comment: Does [`System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("folder")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25519078/950488) work? If not, my next guess would be to check permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a permission issue.  Apparently the location the game files exist is readonly, so adding the Saves folder was giving an IOException.  The simple solution is to move the saves to [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

```
string relPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Saves/saveData.txt";
```

If that doesn't work, look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42953594/1618257) on how to setup `Application.logMessageReceived` so you can catch the general exception, which will offer an actual error message to look into.